# Netflix on Chrome 40 not working

Tags: google-chrome, netflix, drm

I'm using Ubuntu 14.10 with Google Chrome 40.0.2214, libnss3 3.17 with nvidia graphic card.

I've read about everywhere the steps "Install Ubuntu, Install Chrome, Profit!", but in none of my 3 different computers netflix seems to work.

The error is just "Unexpected Error" (looks like someone forgot a try/except) and the useless error code M7354 (there is no error code database for Netflix, and googleing that shows nothing related).

I tried to use google chrome's developer tools to check for errors on Console and maybe Network tab, but there are no errors.

I also tried to disable 2D acceleration, but not works either.

Should I just give up on trying to watch movies/series legally and walk the wrong way?